# R function with is.numeric as paste value

Tags: r, function

I prepare for an exam, including some R basics. In our exercises, we have the following function:

```
test <- function(x){
  if(is.logical(x)) {x <- is.numeric(x)}
  if(!is.numeric(x)) {x <- seq(2,10,length.out = length(x))}
  rval <- x
  return(rval)
}
```

Further we have following Values:

```
x <- c(2,3,5,7)
y <- c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
z <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Now we should know what R will show for:

(1) `test(x)`

(2) `test(y)`

(3) `test(z)`

I'm fine with (1) and (2) but got no idea about (3), as the argument `{x <- is.numeric(x)}` doesn't make sense to me.

Anyways, the answer is "2". But I don't understand it.
Maybe you got any ideas about? I couldn't reason it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function, the 'x' or the input is converted to a single logical `FALSE`, if it is logical

```
if(is.logical(x)) {
    x <- is.numeric(x)
  }
```

This value returns `FALSE` as it is not `numeric`.

In the next line of code, it is evaluating the input again

```
if(!is.numeric(x))
```

Here, the `FALSE` returns `TRUE` and executes the following line

```
x <- seq(2,10,length.out = length(x))
```

which would be translated to

```
seq(2, 10, length.out = 1)
```

because

```
length(FALSE) # is 1
```